# Gnosis Safe deploying same address on multiple chains - error

Tags: gnosis-safe

I deployed the same gnosis ETH safe onto ARB so that I have the same Safe address on both chains.

However, after I load the safe on ARB I can an error: 'This safe was created with an unsupported base contract. The web interface might not work correctly. We recommend using the command line interface instead'.

What is this error about? Basically, I'd like to know whether I have deployed the safe correctly and securely on ARB.

It appears I can still access and use the UI with the recreated Safe on ARB but I'd like to know whether there are any security risks on accessing Safe this way?